# indexOf refuses to work inside vue mutation when action is using promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-promise, vuex

I do get some problems getting indexOf inside vuex mutation to work when I use action with a promise. This is my action

```
export const deleteItem = ({commit}, item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Vue.http.delete(item.url, item)
           .then(response => {
               commit(types.DELETE_ITEM, {response, item})
               resolve(response)
           })
           .catch(error => {
               commit(types.ERROR, error)
               reject(error)
           })
    })
}
```

This is my mutation

```
[types.DELETE_ITEM](state, {response, item}) {
   state.notifications = {
            display:    true,
            type:       'success',
            ok:         response.ok,
            status:     response.status,
            statusText: response.statusText,
            body:       response.body
        }
        state.items.splice(state.items.indexOf(item), 1)
    }
```

I am getting an error indexOf is not a function does anyone know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid enough to reassign state.items array to an object down in the code and indexOf function disappeared.